# VirtualBox installation after kernel update

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, kernel

After updating Kernel in Ubuntu 16.04, I recognized that VirtualBox stopped working.

[image: VirtualBox error]

I looked for solution and followed described solution:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt install --reinstall virtualbox-dkms && sudo apt install libelf-dev
```

And there was another error:
[Second error appeared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPGPL.png)

Then I looked for solution to this error and recognized I had to do:

```
$ sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
```

And there was another error:

[image: error message]

`/var/log/vbox-setup.log error` :

[image]

Software I have:

- gcc/g++ (Ubuntu 7.1.0-10ubuntu1~16.04.york0) 7.1.0
- cc/c++ (Ubuntu 7.1.0-10ubuntu1~16.04.york0) 7.1.0
- Linux 4.15.0-55-generic #60~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 4 09:03:09 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

That's a really old version of VirtualBox. I would try moving up to the 5.2 branch (currently on release 32).